# docked bottom div that works in mobile safari

Tags: jquery, css

i want to add a docked-bottom menu at a webpage, also center aligned. I tried with css and position:fixed like:

```
footer{
  position:fixed;
  width:980px;
  bottom:0px;
  left:50%;
  margin-left:-490px;
}
```

This seems to work on all browsers but zooming in results of showing only the center of the footer and hidden the edges. overflow:scroll has no effect. So i thought of using position:absolute combined with jquery. So the css is:

```
footer{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
}
```

and the jQuery:

```
function hscrollbar() {
   var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop();// + $(window).height();
   $('#footer').css('bottom', -scrollBottom + 'px');
}
window.onscroll = hscrollbar; /* Call the function when the user scrolls */
window.onresize = hscrollbar; /* Call the function when the window resizes */
```

which seems to work on Chrome, FF etc... and zooming in does not hide the footer, but again in mobile Safari the result is not the expected. On zooming/resizing the footer is not moved at all and on scrolling it keeps going down.

So how could i add a docked bottom menu that does not hide on zooming in out and also works on mobile Safari?